# Viewing .swf Code Without Editing

Tags: swfupload

I have a .swf file that I want to show people. I thought it would be a good idea for them to be able to view the code, but I don't want them to be able to edit it, so then they don't mess up my work. Are there any good programs for that? I'm using windows.

Comment: Why don't publish the source code along with the .swf file?

Comment: @user3545752 how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

> Do you want .swf on website? If so you can use html code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<embed src="helloworld.swf">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you don't want people view your code you can put that code on database as people can't view code that has been coming from the database.